# Oracle How to use Merge Into for insert or update based on select

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sql-insert

I have a customers table as shown

Based on select result, I am trying to do an insert or update operation based on it

```
CREATE TABLE customers  
(
    customer_id     number(10) NOT NULL,  
    customer_serial number(10)
);
```

I am trying to do the following 3 steps

1. I am fetching customer_serial from customers based on customer_id
2. If no data is found, making an insert into customers (25 is hardcoded value for `customer_serial`)
3. Else if data found, doing an update (adding 10 to existing `customer_serial`)

Code:

```
MERGE INTO customers 
USING (SELECT customer_serial 
       FROM customers 
       WHERE customer_id = 2) cust 

WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
        INSERT (customer_id, customer_serial) 
        VALUES (customer_id, 25) 

WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN 
        UPDATE 
            SET customer_serial = cust.customer_serial + 10 
        WHERE 
            customer_id = 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/CpyHhLUY

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the following syntax:

```
merge into customers c
using (select 2 as customer_id from dual) s
on (c.customer_id = s.customer_id)
when not matched then insert (customer_id, customer_serial) values (s.customer_id , 25) 
when matched then update set c.customer_serial = c.customer_serial + 10
```

Starting from the given customer id (here `2`), which is defined in the `using` clause, the query searches for a corresponding record in the table (that's the `on` clause). If such row does not exist, the `when not matched` clause inserts the id with a fixed serial of `25`, else the `when matched` clause increments the existing serial.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jS32Gg1B)

Comment: Thank you very much its working .
Is it possibe to return  the  customer_serial  value from the same query (the merge  into) , without an extra select query ?

Comment: @Lavanya: unfortunately I don't think that Oracle supports the `RETURNING` clause for `MERGE`, so you would probably need an additional query to fetch the new customer serial.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `ON` clause and can simplify the query to:

```sql
MERGE INTO customers
USING DUAL
ON (customer_id = 2)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT (customer_id, customer_serial) VALUES (2, 25) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET customer_serial = customer_serial + 10;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HJ6DTa4h)